# C#: Finding and changing an element in an array of struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, pass-by-reference

I have a struct *TableRow* and an array *table* of such structs:

```
table = new TableRow[10];
```

Now I want to find and manipulate the content of one of the structs in the array. 
I use Array.Find to search the right array element:

```
var tr = Array.Find( table, tRow => tRow.color == 'red' );
tr.count++;
```

Problem is that structs are value types and so the Find method returns a copy of the struct that I want to manipulate. Changing this copy does not change the struct in the array.

I can't seem to find any way to instruct the Find method to return the struct by reference.

Comment: Could you show TableRow struct body? It is really rare case when you need custom struct type, think about converting it to a class if its  total fields size more than 16bytes

Comment: …or if any of the fields need to be changed after initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the way `Find()` works for value types.  You can either convert your `struct` to a `class` -- typically we only use `struct` for very small (<= 16 byte) value types that represent a "single" value anyway.  MSDN has good guidance on `struct` vs `class` here: [Chossing Between Classes and Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

Or you can use `FindIndex()` to get the position in the array, and then use that to modify the field.

```
var pos = Array.FindIndex(table, tRow => tRow.color == 'red');

if (pos >= 0)
{
    table[pos].count++
}
```

Comment: Thanks, James. Most complete and fastest of three answer, so you get the check mark.

Comment: Thanks!  When I first got into C# I had many preconceived notions of struct vs class, they are very different birds each with their own pros and cons.  As Douglas said, because of their pass-by-value semantics they do tend to be best for immutable values (`DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, etc are all prime examples) and because they're only more "efficient" if they are <= 16 bytes (in general) they tend to be best for single-ish values (again like `DateTime`, etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FindIndex` to get the zero-based index of the matching element, and alter that instead.

```
int i = Array.FindIndex(table, tRow => tRow.color == 'red');
table[i].count++;
```

However, it is recommended that structs should (almost always) be immutable. Per the MSDN link @James provided (emphasis added):

> > Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following characteristics:
> >
> > - It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types (integer, double, and so on).
> > - It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
> > - **It is immutable.**
> > - It will not have to be boxed frequently.

Since you intend to update the `count` of your `TableRow` instances, then you shouldn’t be using a struct in the first place. In my opinion, you would be better off just converting it to a class.

Comment: Thanks Douglas. The clear hint that structs should always be immutable  made me quickly find more information about that topic. I will definitely convert to class.

Answer (score 2):

Because structures are value types you have to create a new instance of a TableRow and replace the desired element with it.
You can use Array.FindIndex to find the index of your element.